# How systemd receive the poweroff signal?

Tags: linux, systemd

Systemd logind can handle the power button to do shutdown or sleep.

https://superuser.com/questions/699905/change-behavior-of-linux-power-button/699925
( see Sam Hanes' answer )

When short press the power button, systemd will trigger shutdown.

Here is my question, I can't find the source code where triggers the shutdown.

Here is the systemd github:

https://github.com/systemd/systemd

I think BIOS should first know the user press the power button, but what signal? what kind of transition that systemd also know the power button is pressed?

I see the kernel acpi driver also have the button.c, who actually handle the button? acpi button.c? systemd or acpid?

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/defb53a7c790f9e37a765de8a5d830ed15e2055b/drivers/acpi

Comment: Start with `HandlePowerKey` option and see how is it parsed in source - then build the way down to seeing what does it affect, you will get to receiving the event. `systemd` are big sources, you may see what `udev` and `apicd` has.

Comment: On modern systems, power button is really just a soft button, akin to any other key on the keyboard (as far as user space is concerned). Thus, it will simply generate an "input" event on one of the "/dev/input/event*" devices.

Comment: so, systemd and acpid just read event from /dev/input/event* ?

Answer (score -1):

I think BIOS should first know the user press the power button, but what signal? what kind of transition that systemd also know the power button is pressed?
<< It depends on power button design, it could be super IO/EC or PCH connetion.

Comment: the signal here I mean software signal.